# Count the downtime for Logical connection using MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I need weekly count for Logical connection down only. The week should be started from 1st of that month. The count can be for any (downtime or conn_type)

| ID | conn_type | downtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | logical | 2022-04-02 12:12:12.000 |
| 2 | physical | 2022-04-03 12:12:12.000 |
| 3 | logical | 2022-04-03 12:12:12.000 |
| 4 | logical | 2022-04-04 12:12:12.000 |

Output Table for Logical connection down -

| From_date | To_date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-07 | 10 |
| 2022-04-08 | 2022-04-14 | 4 |
| 2022-04-15 | 2022-04-21 | 3 |
| 2022-04-22 | 2022-04-28 | 1 |

I have tried this query -

with temp as (
select dates, datepart(WEEK,dates) as vr, count(comp_type) over (partition by datepart(WEEK,dates)) as total_count
from date_buckets where comp_type = 'logical') select distinct min(dates) over (partition by vr) as week_start,
max(dates) over (partition by vr) as week_end,
total_count
from temp

but unable to get the desired results.

Comment: You need a calendar table of `Weeks` then you left join this table to it

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72741991/edit) your question to show what query/ies you've tried so far and tell us why you think they aren't working as you expect. "I need..." is not a question and is unlikely to garner much help. See also, [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)